# How do I get the axes for SAT collision detection

Tags: collision-detection, vector, separating-axis-theorem

In SAT collision detection how do I calculate the axes for projection?

Comment: This question shows lack of research :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll initially stick to 2D collisions detection for simplicity. (I'll discuss 3D at the end).

The axes used in SAT are the normal vectors of all of the edges of the two objects being considered.

Consider the box in this diagram;
[image]

The box has 4 edges: AB,BC,CD & DA (if using the clockwise convention). Each of these edges can be written as a vector;

1. edge AB  is the vector B-A. (That is vectorB minus vectorA)
2. A & B are points, the expression (B-A) is the vector which encapsulates the distance and direction from point A to point B.
3. We need the normal to this edge, A normal is vector at right angles to the edge. We can calculate this by swapping x and y of the edge and multiplying the y value by -1.

I'll do a numerical example;

```
A=(100,100)
B=(150,175)

edgeAB B-A=(150-100,175-100)=(50, 75)

normalAB=(-75, 50)
```

For SAT we need also to find  normalBC, normalCD and normal DA. We also need to find the normals to all the edges of the other object in the collision detection.

All these normals are the set of **axes** which we will project both objects' vertices onto.

In some tutorials you will be advised to normalise the axes. this is not necessary, although I find  it does make visualising the process easier.

Note, in the diagram, normalAB is parallel with normalCD in this case the result of projection on these axes will be the same (overlap or non-overlap) will be the same so there is no need to project on to both of them. You can eliminate normal CD. Similarly normal BC and normal DA are parallel, so you can eliminate one of these.

#### 3D normals

For 3D you will need to find the normals for all the faces, you will also need to get the cross product of all the edges of one object with all the edges of the other.

Comment: Just a note that the component you negate when finding the normal depends on winding order.  If clockwise, negate the X component after swapping.  If counter-clockwise, negate the Y component after swappibg.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch, that's true if you want 'outward' pointing normals, but it turns out that for SAT it doesn't really matter if you use 'outward' or 'inward' normals. Either will give you the same result

Comment: That's a good point.  I didn't think that one through. :)

Comment: Is there a reason you keep answering your own questions ( full articles answered within a minute of posting the question ) and then selecting it as the accepted answer? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40011/how-do-i-rotate-a-sprite-so-that-it-is-pointing-in-the-direction-it-is-moving and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38841/get-sfml-to-report-the-version-of-opengl-that-is-being-used

Comment: @rootlocus, I'm trying to maximize the value of my keystrokes http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/05/maximizing-the-value-of-your-keystrokes.html If I have to answer a programming question  for someone(outside of SE), I'll put it up here for future reference